# bootstrap affix offset calculation VS font line-height

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I use a web font like Myriad pro via Typekit the line-height kills my calculation of bootstrap affix offset from top. I'm using following code:

```
var navOffset = $('#nav').offset();
$('#nav').affix({
    offset: {
        top: navOffset.top
    }
});
```

It seems that the script uses the line-height of the fall back font to calculate the offset. Any ideas to prevent this? Changing the line-heigth from em to px hasn't any effect. Thanks for reply.

Comment: In css I'm using `body{ font-family: "myriad-pro",sans-serif; }` and if I comment this, everything works as aspected. strange.

Comment: with font enabled `Object { top: 4447.033203125, left: 144.5 }`  
and disabled `Object { top: 4514.61669921875, left: 144.5 }`

Comment: Google Fonts works well, it's a Typekit problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by changing the loading method from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/xxxxxx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(d) {
    var config = {
      kitId: 'xxxxxxx',
      scriptTimeout: 3000
    },
    h=d.documentElement,t=setTimeout(function(){h.className=h.className.replace(
    /\bwf-loading\b/g,"")+" wf-inactive";},config.scriptTimeout),tk=d.createElement(
    "script"),f=false,s=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],a;h.className+=" wf-loading";
    tk.src='//use.typekit.net/'+config.kitId+'.js';tk.async=true;tk.onload=tk.onreadyst
    atechange=function(){a=this.readyState;if(f||a&&a!="complete"&&a!="loaded")return;
    f=true;clearTimeout(t);try{Typekit.load(config)}catch(e){}};s.parentNode.insertBefore(tk,s)
      })(document);
</script>
```

scriptTimeout do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set a timeout for the offset script

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var navOffset = $('#nav').offset();
  $('#nav').affix({
    offset: {
      top: navOffset.top
    }
  });
}, 3000);
```